# How to delete or replace a line in a text file

Tags: batch-file

```
@Echo Off
    for /R directory %%F IN (*.js) DO ( 
       // delete the string 'Success' if written in the file ???
        echo %%~nF >> Output.txt
        echo Success >> Output.txt 
    )
```

Please see at line 3 : How to delete a string 'Success' in the same file if found.

line 5 : it always write the `success` at the end of file.

BTW i can achieve the same by  writing 'success' in to the file just out of the loop, but i have such a scenario where i have to apply this logic.

Comment: if that's of any help i can help you do it in c#...

Comment: Batch is a terrible language for doing this. Are you free to chose a different language? As for line 5: you must move that line outside the loop if you want that message only at the end of `Output.txt`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Line 5 is even more of a problem because of processing multiple files.  Outside the loop isn't the solution...

Comment: @foxidrive It is if he wants the message to appear at the end of the file. If that's not what he wants he needs to explain in far more detail when and where he wants the message to appear.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers that is not possible to choose different language because of i am working on existing project which requires some modification. If i choose any different then i need to take care of included library file too which will take much time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `findstr` word to do that.
try

```
findstr /v "Success" infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

two things:

- "> outfile.txt" will send the results to the file outfile.txt instead printing them to your console. (Note that it will overwrite the file if it exists. Use ">> outfile.txt" instead if you want to append.)
- You might also consider adding the /i switch to do a case-insensitive match.